# no popup window asterisk 11 with vtiger crm

Tags: php, asterisk, vtiger, pbx

I'm new to asterisk, i was trying to integrate asterisk 11 (with freepbx 2.11) to vTiger 5.4.0. Everything are working fine without this simple problem. The problem is with incoming calls from queue, pop-up window appears after answering the call ! Please help me... i was googling for last 3 days to find a solution.

Manager.conf:

```
[general]
enabled = yes
port = 5038
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
displayconnects=no 

[admin]
secret = Fr33WEASLJ!@3dft
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=127.0.0.1/255.255.255.0
read = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,originate
write = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,command,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,originate
writetimeout = 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your dialplan to put event for popup BEFORE calling, not in on-answer-macro

Macro will be executed AFTER answer, so yes, you got popup after answer.

I can't say why developer of plugin did so, but you always can change that.